# regex for a list of <a> tags

Tags: html, regex

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="tags">
<a href="/tag:SD_Card_Holder">SD_Card_Holder</a>
,
<a href="/tag:Thumb_Drive">thumb_drive</a>
</div>
```

I need to take only the content within `<a>` tags, in this case: `SD_Card_Holder` and `thumb_drive`.

My `regex` is the following:

```
(?s)class="tags">[^<]*?<a href="\/tag:(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/div>
```

The result I get is:

```
SD_Card_Holder
SD_Card_Holder, thumb_drive
```

the second has the first occurrence and I need to avoid this.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Comment: Also, how do you 'get' the result? If it's something like a simple `console.log`, then it's the log print function that coerces an array result into a comma separated string.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I'm using OpenSearchServer. In the crawler section.

Comment: Unless you need to do more, something like this probably would work `href="/tag:([^>"]+)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well know that you shouldn't use regex to parse xhtml unless you are sure what html you are going to use. However, if you want to use a regex you can use a regex like this:

```
<a.*?:(.*?)">
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iL0uI2/1)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [33-47] `SD_Card_Holder`
MATCH 2
1.  [84-95] `Thumb_Drive`
```

Comment: almost work!  but need to filter other a tags which do not contain /tag

Comment: Ok, thanks!!!  I changed it and now it works perfectly!! I used this: <a.*?\/tag:(.*?)">

Answer (score 0):

First: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Second: Lookup using xpath selectors.

`xmllint --xpath "string(//a[1])" foo.html`

`xmllint --xpath "string(//a[2])" foo.html`

`...`

Comment: I think the flaw in that discussion you've linked, is that people who parse html with regular expressions don't give a hoot about `HTML, on the other hand, has structures that can nest arbitrarily deep.` as quoted. They are primarily interested in parsing tags, not the _entire_ document as a whole. A general regex exists to go past comment tags and others, to get to the real tags. Parsing a tag itself requires a little finesse but is doable and reliable.